# c# Removing an object from list based on 2 variables

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list

I'm trying to remove an object from a list, First I need to get all the entries in it with the id == 0(for now) and then remove the first entry. At the moment I'm trying:

```
coursework.Where( x => x.Id == moduleList.SelectedIndex).remove(coursework[testList.SelectedIndex]) // Doesnt exist in this context
```

But that doesn't work and I've tried many things but can never find anything that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Where()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` containing matched items.
It cannot be used to modify the original list.

Instead, you should call `.RemoveAll()`.

Comment: How would I do that so it only removes the one with matching ID and then the matching [] ID?

Comment: @Kennyist: `RemoveAll` takes a lambda expression specifying which items to remove (just like `Where()`).